# Ionic - Upgrade to Angular 10 with ionic-angular problem

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I upgraded my Ionic app to Angular 10 and I have some errors with the `angular-ionic` package, even if I upgraded also this to its latest version 3.9.10. The errors are related to the `Renderer` package which seems to be used by `angular-ionic`:

> Typescript Error Module '"../../../@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'Renderer'. Did you mean 'Renderer2'?

> node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/navigation/nav-util.d.ts

> import { Renderer, TypeDecorator } from '@angular/core';

I know `Renderer` is replaced by `Renderer2` in the newest versions of Angular, so I replaced this inside my app, but why `angular-ionic` still complains about this? Is it still using this package?
I removed `node_modules` and installed all the packages again.
Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: Remove node_modules folder and do `npm install` again

Comment: I already did that. I mentioned it in the initial post.

Comment: What about removing the package-lock.json, the node_modules folder and do `npm install`

Comment: If that doesn't work, please share the content of your package.json

Comment: It seems the solution is to upgrade also Ionic to a newer version as I am using 3.9. :)